# import @react-pdf-viewer/core in meteor js 2.2 cause a problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, meteor, react-pdf-viewer

import {Worker ,Viewer} from @react-pdf-viewer/core;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUHUq.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please copy the code from command line and paste it here as formatted code instead of attaching images. Then some more question: do you use webpack with Meteor? I'm asking because there is an `@` in your import. If so, please add your webpack config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys the problem was caused by a conflict with library es6-symbols

Answer (score 1):

you can use a worker like this.

```
<Worker workerUrl="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.13.216/build/pdf.worker.min.js">
  <Viewer fileUrl={url} />
</Worker>
```